# Aurelia. How to connect the js file and print a simple function alert?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Help please. How to connect the **javascript** file and print a simple function **alert**?

Comment: It would be helpful to go into more detail as well as to provide information on what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to linking a JS file to an HTML file? Because if you are, you can use the  tag in the head to link it. If you are using pure JS, you would add an "onclick" handler to call a function in your JS file that would then call alert() with whatever you wanted to put on the alert that would pop up.

an example of a script tag could be `<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>`

and in your JS, you could have a function called "run" that would do the alert. The "onclick" could be like this `<button onclick="run()">`

Here are some links that will help you:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Hope that helps!

Comment: I try  it http://prntscr.com/eessqj but get the message 
Resource «http://localhost: 9000 /myscript.js» has been blocked due to a mismatch of type MIME (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: Try moving the JS script to the bottom of the `<body>` (but not outside of it)